# How to look if a value typed in a text box exists in a data grid-view?

Tags: c#, datagridview, textbox

I have a `dataGridView1` and the user can enter info to it, then by clicking a `button3` I want the user to search for whatever he types in a `textBox3` And to get a `MessageBox` saying if the string was found or not in the `datagridview`.
My code is

```
bool exists = false;
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    if (exists == true)
    {
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        for (int k = 1; k < dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells.Count; k++)
        {
            if (textBox3.Text == dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[k].Value.ToString())
            {
                exists = true;
                break;
            }

        }
    }
}

if (exists == true)
{
    MessageBox.Show("It exists!");
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("It doesn't exist!!");
}
```

Comment: Showing your code will allow us to help you.  Without any code, it's hard for us to picture your issue for your particular situation.

Comment: how are you binding this DataGridView? please include some code. so i can give you a better answer :)

Comment: Enhanced question by adding formatting, enhanced title by using general names, added relevant tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing some actual code its hard to get specific, here's what I would do:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string SearchString = textBox3.text;
    try
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            if (row.Cells[SearchColumn.SelectedIndex].Value.ToString().Equals(SearchString))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Match Found");
                //This will only pick up the first match not multiple…
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No Match");
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Completely untested, essentially you want to be doing the following:

- Search through each row of your grid
- convert the value to string (error catch here)
- compare the row value to your string (from textbox3)

Have fun.

Comment: in if(row.Cells[SearchColumn.SelectedIndex].Value.ToString().Equals(SearchString))

Comment: the SearchColumn does exist in current context!!